# script not running from jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Guys I have just been working on jsfiddle but when I load it into an offline .html the js script doesnt run? Here is the code in the html file anyone know why??

Sorry im new to using jsfiddle and not sure why I cant just copy and paste the code I work on into a html file when im offline to work on it further.

Thank you for all the help!

```
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th width="20%">Value</th>
        <th width="20%">Quantity</th>
        <th class="actions">Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" class="input-small" name="var_1" value="60">60</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_1_1" value="0"></td>
        <td>$<span class="amount"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_2" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_2_2" value="0"></td>
        <td>$<span class="amount"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><strong>Total event cost (viability)</strong></td>
        <td><strong>$<div class="total_amount">total</div></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table><button>Go!</button>

<script>
    function doCalc() {
    var total = 0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('span.amount').html($('input:eq(0)', this).val() * $('input:eq(1)', this).val());
    });
    $('.amount').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
    });
    $('div.total_amount').html(total);
}
$('button').click(doCalc);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery library?

Comment: You have to learn how to debug javascript using your console. You should see error saying `$` is undefined

Comment: You have to include jQuery: the syntax $(...) is typical for this library.

Comment: And it's better to set event handlers after document load. `$(function() {$('button').click(doCalc);});`

Comment: you need to select the jquery library from the left sidebar javascript dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Your script depends on jQuery. You haven't included the jQuery library in your HTML. [Download it](http://jquery.com/download/) and then add another script element for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please include `jQuery`

Use `Google CDN`

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And if you want to use it offline just download it from the above `src` link and then use it.

Comment: jsfiddle provide jQuery

Comment: I'd suggest using `//ajax.googleapis....` instead of `http://ajax.googleapis...`. This way it doesn't matter if you're on http or https

Comment: Yes he is saying, when he creates a `html` file out of that code then it does not work.

Comment: @Novocaine, Yes that is definiltely better but I am pretty sue he is never gonna use `https://`

Comment: but other people might ;-)